# In my tiny tower extra floors are appearing beneath my lobby

Tags: tiny-tower

It has happened three times now over the course of three days. The first two times it happened three floors appeared all at once. They were all sushi bars and I didn't pay for any of them. The third time this occurred I still did not pay for any of the floors, but there was now four sushi bar floors that appeared. Now I have ten sushi bars and they are all beneath my lobby. Does anyone else have this problem and how can I stop it?

Comment: It happened again a few minutes ago I got four more sushi shop floors which makes it a total of 14 sushi bars

Comment: If you know how to fix this please tell me I now have a total of 18 sushi shops!